# Probability of three points on a 4 dimensional cubes forming an equilateral triangle

Tags: probability, geometry

There are three points that are randomly chosen from the corners of a four-dimensional cube. What is the probability that the three points form an equilateral triangle?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Do we know for sure that the randomly chosen points will be at the corners of the $4$-$D$ cube? Or are we only given that the randomly chosen points will be on the edges of the $4$-$D$ cube?

Comment: The points are on the corners.

Comment: I just read that this question is closed for being "off-topic". I don't understand why this is the case. This is definitely a math question, and this is definitely a math question that belongs to this site, as opposed to MathOverflow. Is there something I'm missing? If anyone involved with the closure is willing to take the time to comment, then I would happy to read what they have to say. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard Did you read the rest of the closure notice? "This question is missing context or other details: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc." Problems with no context and no work by the author are routinely closed for this reason, and it should be no surprise that this poor-quality question was closed as well.

Comment: @KReiser First, thank you for taking the time to respond to my question. I'm new to this site, and I have a lot to learn. I want to be using this site properly, and I appreciate your patience.

Comment: @KReiser You asked if I read the rest of the closure notice. I'm afraid I don't know what you mean. When I log onto this page, I see a message that this question is closed, and there are links to general information about which questions are off-topic and which questions are off-topic. I've clicked those links, and I've read both of those pages. But both of those links contain additional links, and I haven't looked at all of those additional links yet. There doesn't seem to be any information specific to this question. Is this because I've only been here two months and my rep is too low?

Comment: @KReiser I appreciate your time. Thanks for giving me an answer to my question.

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard it appears that detailed closure notices on other users posts were restricted to those with 3k rep about a month ago as per [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide). This is why the notice appears like it does to you - the copy/pasted quote in my previous comment is what you're missing. The issue with this question and those like it is that isolated problems with little/no work by the asker aren't [good questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard when one encounters a post like this, it is generally better to engage via the comments first and ask the OP to improve their post by adding context and their own attempts instead of answering straight away.

Comment: @KReiser I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

We can think of the cube as $[0,1]^4=\{(w,x,y,z)\,|\,0\le w,x,y,z\le1\}$.

The set of corners will then be $\{0,1\}^4$.

If we did pick an equilateral triangle from amongst the corners, it's helpful to think about how long the sides would be. Let $X,Y\in\{0,1\}^4$. So $X=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, $Y=(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)$ for some $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4\in\{0,1\}$. Note that the distance between $X$ and $Y$ is

$$d(X,Y)=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^4(y_i-x_i)^2}.$$

Note also that $(y_i-x_i)^2=0$ iff $x_i=y_i$, and $(y_i-x_i)^2=1$ iff $x_i\ne y_i$. Hence $d(X,Y)$ is either $0$, $1$, $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$, or $2$. It follows that if $D=d(X,Y)$, then $D^2$ is the number of coordinates at which $X$, $Y$ differ.

We can use this to show the following: let $A,B,C\in\{0,1\}^4$. If triangle $ABC$ is equilateral, then $d(A,B)=\sqrt{2}$. We can prove this by eliminating the cases where $d(A,B)=0,1,\sqrt{3},2$.

Let's do so now: suppose triangle $ABC$ is equilateral. Our goal is to show that $d(A,B)\ne0,1,\sqrt{3},2$.

If $d(A,B)=0$, then $A=B$, so we can't have $d(A,B)=0$.

If $d(A,B)=1$, then without loss of generality $A=(0,0,0,0)$ and $B=(1,0,0,0)$. Since $d(B,C)=1$ and $C\ne A$, $C$ must be one of $(1,1,0,0)$, $(1,0,1,0)$, or $(1,0,0,1)$. In each case, $d(A,C)=\sqrt{2}$. So it can't be the case that $d(A,B)=1$.

If $d(A,B)=\sqrt{3}$, then without loss of generality $A=(0,0,0,0)$ and $B=(1,1,1,0)$. Since $d(B,C)= \sqrt{3} $ and $C\ne A$, $C$ must be one of $(1,0,0,1)$, $(0,1,0,1)$, or $(0,0,1,1)$. In each case, $d(A,C)=\sqrt{2}$. So it can't be the case that $d(A,B)= \sqrt{3} $.

Finally, it can't be the case that $d(A,B)=2$, since for each corner $X$, there is only one other corner $Y$ with $d(X,Y)=2$.

So an equilateral triangle formed from corners of $\{0,1\}^4$ will have sides of length $\sqrt{2}$. Now that we know what to look for, it will be easier to calculate the probability.

Suppose we pick three points at random from $\{0,1\}^4$. There are $16$ possibilities for the first point, $15$ possibilities for the second, and $14$ possibilities for the third. Hence there are $16\cdot15\cdot14$ overall.

Now suppose we pick three points at random from $\{0,1\}^4$ and get an equilateral triangle. Let $A=(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ be the first point. There are still $16$ possibilities for $A$.  Let $B=(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)$ be the second point. Since $d(A,B)=\sqrt{2}$, $B$ must differ from $A$ at two of its four coordinates. Hence there are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ choices for the $B$. Let $C=(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4)$ be the third point. It remains to find the number of choices for $C$.

Note that $B$ has two coordinates in common with $A$, let's say that $a_i=b_i$, and $a_j=b_j$ for some distinct $i,j\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. We also have $a_m\ne b_m$ and $a_n\ne b_n$ for some distinct $m,n$ such that $\{i,j,n,m\}=\{1,2,3,4\}$. To get triangle $ABC$ to be equilateral, we must have $C$ differ from $B$ at exactly one of $i$, $j$, and exactly one of $n$, $m$. Hence there are four possiblities for $C$.

So the probability that the triangle is equilateral is $\dfrac{16\cdot6\cdot4}{16\cdot15\cdot14}=\dfrac{4}{35}$.